# Jquery drag and drop plugin between tables

Tags: jquery, plugins, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for a jquery plugin that makes it possible to drag and drop between two different tables. I have a table containing search results and I want to make it possible to drag each result to another table to be able to add them to that table. Anyone got an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, tables may not be the best solution. However, you could try using lists instead, then connect them through ui-sortable, using [connected lists](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists).

In doing so, you will also be able to easily extract the order your user puts the lists in.

May not be exactly what you're after, but it's certainly worth a look :)

Answer (score 2):

For the love of all that is holy and just and beautiful, please don't try to do anything with tables that requires you to know where the mouse pointer is relative to the tables. The amount of hurt you will receive will probably drive you insane. If the interface you're designing requires drag and drop, use something like divs or paragraphs or anything that uses the good old box model.

Comment: Oh sorry maybe "table" wasn't the right word. What I mean is a list that comes from a asp.net DataList, so it would work with divs for example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, [jQuery List DragSort](http://dragsort.codeplex.com/)?
BTW, you'll have to define all draggable elements (it's quite easy to do in it's API)